# Could not send second message over TCP/IP

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am trying to send message over TCP/IP in c# application using `TCPClient` and `TCPListner` classes

Following is my code which i got from codeproject site.

**Client** `code written over btn click`

```
try
        {
            TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");

            tcpclnt.Connect("192.168.0.102", 8001);
            // use the ipaddress as in the server program

            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
            //Console.Write("Enter the string to be transmitted : ");

            String str = textBox1.Text;
            Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(str);
            Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");

            stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);

            byte[] bb = new byte[100];
            int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);

            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));


            tcpclnt.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + ex.Message);
        }
```

**Server** `code written on form_load`

```
try
        {
            IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.102");
            // use local m/c IP address, and 
            // use the same in the client

            /* Initializes the Listener */
            TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 8001);

            /* Start Listeneting at the specified port */
            myList.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("The server is running at port 8001...");
            Console.WriteLine("The local End point is  :" +
                              myList.LocalEndpoint);
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.....");

            Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);

            byte[] b = new byte[100];
            int k = s.Receive(b);
            Console.WriteLine("Recieved...");
            string str = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));
                str = str + Convert.ToChar(b[i]);

            }
            label1.Text = str;
            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
            s.Send(asen.GetBytes("The string was recieved by the server."));
            Console.WriteLine("\nSent Acknowledgement");
            /* clean up */
            s.Close();
           // myList.Stop();

        }
```

Here on `client`, i m sending string written in textbox over `tcp` and it well recieved by `server`.

But when i trying to send another string, it fails without any `exception` and client application hangs for infinite time.

What is wrong here ?

Comment: While this is not your main issue: TCP/IP is stream-based, not message-based. Code like this is fatally flawed: you may never assume that a particular call to `Receive` receives a particular number of bytes. All you can be sure of is that if the client writes `N` bytes, some combination of `Receive` calls will eventually receive all `N` bytes. Code like this can work fine in test setups over local sockets, and fail badly when put to work in an actual network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server should always be in listening mode, i.e the server code should be in while loop such that it can accept clients continuously. Your server will accept one client and then close itself. Therefore, if you click client's button, a new client tries to connect to server, but now the server won't be available.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code you provided, the server only attempts to read 1 message from the client, so needs to be put in a loop to read the multiple incoming messages from the client, process the message and send response and then get more messages.

Note also that the server currently expects only one client to ever connect, processes that client and then closes.

The client is set up basically the same in the example, so you  cant modify how one works without also modifying the other.